# Не получается устранить утечку памяти Android приложения

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, outofmemoryerror, glide

Я парсю новости с одного портала и отображаю их в прилаге. Прилага состоит из двух фрагментов. В первом фрагменте список новостей, во втором - непосредственно тело самой новости. Тело новости состоит из множества `TextView` и `ImageView`. Бывают новости, где кол-во картинок достигает 30-40. Если открыть несколько новостей, то прилага работает исправно, но потом при открытии следующей новости вылетает со следующей ошибкой:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3620172 byte allocation with 557008 free bytes and 543KB until OOM
```

Я так понимаю, что это утечка памяти, но я не понимаю, как ее устранить. Картинки в новость я вставляю при помощи библиотеки Glide. Кидаю ей спарсенные url картинок, а она уже вставляет их в ImageView.
Пробовал при `onDestroy()` фрагмента с телом новости просто удалять все созданные вьюхи, но такой способ мне не помогает, ошибка остается.
Помогите, пожалуйста! :)

Answer (score 3):

Нет, это не утечка памяти - это попытка отрисовать слишком большой битмап. Для отрисовки битмапа, который нормально помещается в память сначала надо вычислить параметр его масштабирования `inSampleSize`:

```
public int calculateInSampleSize(InputStream is, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Далее сгенерить битмап нужного размера:

```
 InputStream is; //поток откуда читается картинка
 BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inSampleSize=calculateInSampleSize(is, size, size);
 options.inPurgeable=true; // выгружаемая из памяти
 is.reset(); //сбросить поток на начало
 bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options); //получаем битмап который можно уже рисовать на `ImageView`
```

[Почитать здесь](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: А вы не подскажете, может есть подобное решение, но с использованием библиотеки Glide? Я так понимаю, моя проблема лишь в том, что я пытаюсь загрузить слишком большое кол-во изображений, каждое из которых в свою очередь тоже весит очень много? Можно ли с помощью glide уменьшить размер?)

Comment: Я никогда не использовал *Glide*, но вижу что у него есть такой механизм называется `DownSampler` - погуглите.